# What format is this double in and how can I convert it?

Tags: java, math, double, type-conversion

I am reading a legacy webservice that returns doubles in a format I am not familiar with.

some examples are
1.58e-6
1.56e-6
1.45e-6

They should represent doubles like these (for example)
0.000004343

What is this format and how it can be converted?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert like this
1.58e-6=1.58*10^-6=0.00000158

Comment: Thank you! So in java, would I have to break apart the value (As a string).. then put together the equation? Is there not a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was actually rather simple.

```
double dbl = 1.45e-6;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
System.out.println(df.format(dbl));
```

outputs : 0.00000145

Answer (score 1):

It's called scientific notation. Double.parseDouble() can handle it. NB they're not doubles, they are real numbers expressed in text in scientific notation. Double is the target format you want, not this format.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String s = new DecimalFormat("0.##############").format(Double.parseDouble("1.58e-6"));
```